# Как реализовать стандартную карусель на jquery?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать показ следующих трех элементов на jquery? И как сделать чтобы кнопки затухали если нет предыдущих элементов?
Пытался сделать вот так, но я даже не представляю как можно реализовать это на JS. Помогите пожалуйста, спасибо!

Мой JS:

```
$(function()
{
$('.prev').on('click', function()
{
$('.active').prev('item:nth-child(3)').removeClass('active')
$('.active').next('item:nth-child(3)').addClass('active')
})
})
```

Мой HTML:

```
<style>
    .item {
        display: none
    }
    .item.active {
        display: block
    }
</style>
<button class="prev">Назад</button>
<div class="items">
    <div class="item active">1</div>
    <div class="item active">2</div>
    <div class="item active">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
    <div class="item">7</div>
    <div class="item">8</div>
    <div class="item">9</div>
    <div class="item">10</div>
    <div class="item">11</div>
    <div class="item">12</div>
</div>
<button class="next">Вперёд</button>
```

Comment: Наверное слайдер, неправильно выразился))

Comment: На гитхабе полно ванильных слайдеров, толку писать свой, если уже написано тысячу раз.

Comment: понимаю на гитхабе много готовых вариантов, но мне надо понять именно логику реализации подобных слайдеров.